# Social Engine access to view methods

Tags: api, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm coding my API in SocialEngine and i got some problems when I try to call view method that i used to call within a controller, i.e.

- $this->view->htmlLink()
- $this->view->baseUrl()
- $this->view->translate()
- etc.

i found in factory scripts that i can call translate() method from an Api accessing Zend framework, Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->_(), but I guess this may be not the best way (and i didn't find nothing about other methods…)

so, how can I access this methods from my module's API, so that they get through my controller when i call Engine_Api::_()->getApi()->myMethod()?

ty!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this anywhere:

```
$view = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_View');
echo $view->baseUrl();
```

Comment: hi , i am using a plugin name "rest api" , when i create varialbe `$view = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_view);` , then it returns `null`

Comment: Maybe the API has changed.